# Carousel Caption moves to top left when adding image from the local file or from some website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Customizing Modern Business template, carousel caption moves to top left when adding image to the carousel.

HTML

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
```

```
<title>Modern Business - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="services.html">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Portfolio <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="portfolio-1-col.html">1 Column Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="portfolio-2-col.html">2 Column Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="portfolio-3-col.html">3 Column Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="portfolio-4-col.html">4 Column Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="portfolio-item.html">Single Portfolio Item</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Blog <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="blog-home-1.html">Blog Home 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="blog-home-2.html">Blog Home 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="blog-post.html">Blog Post</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Other Pages <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="full-width.html">Full Width Page</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="sidebar.html">Sidebar Page</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="404.html">404</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pricing.html">Pricing Table</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<!-- Header Carousel -->
<header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(http://dressesview.com/wp-content/uploads/purpleweddings008-50b0b984e3cd7.jpg);”></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 1</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(http://dressesview.com/wp-content/uploads/purpleweddings008-50b0b984e3cd7.jpg);”></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(http://dressesview.com/wp-content/uploads/purpleweddings008-50b0b984e3cd7.jpg);”></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 3</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
</header>
```

CSS

```
html,
 body {
height: 100%;
 }

body {
padding-top: 50px; /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using   .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
 }

 .img-portfolio {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 }

.img-hover:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  }

/* Home Page Carousel */

  header.carousel {
   height: 60%;
   }

  header.carousel .item,
   header.carousel .item.active,
   header.carousel .carousel-inner {
   height: 100%;
   }

header.carousel .fill {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}
```

[This is the jsfiddle result showing that caption moves to top left after adding images.](http://jsfiddle.net/yomozon/wnjt9chx/1/)

Comment: You are not adding the image with image tag. I updated your jsfiddle and if you are allowed to use image tag, then copy paste the carousel segment from http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/                         and                                                  http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/carousel.css

Comment: i cannot see your update in jsfiddle can you provide link of updated jsfiddle